# auto publish custom post type when publish different post type

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a wordpress music website based on soundcloud api, 
the thing is that, in my website i have 2 custom post types: albums and artists.
Im trying to auto publish an artist when i am publishing an audio track. i can get all the info for the databse of the artist using soundcloud api but i have no idea how can i auto publish both of them at the same time. 
also needed to be a function that check if this artist already published and if so, not publish again, so there wont be duplicates. it should be filtered by the artist id...

it could be a big time saver. 
any help would be great! 
tnx.

Comment: Research at [wordpress.se], there are solutions for this already answered over there. You'll need to hook into `save_post` or `publish_post`. Look for those keywords and also `post_type`, something [like this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bsave_post%20%2bpost_type%20is%3aa).

Comment: tnx for your response! I'll  take a look at that...

Comment: i couldnt find a good tutorial for my issue.. :(

Comment: It sounded familiar... [I did something quite similar](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83717/12615), should be enough to get started :)